# RSpec lazy subject

Tags: ruby, rspec

When testing class methods, I don't need an instance to be created automatically. Is an implicit subject created automatically, or only when referenced?

```
describe MyClass do

  it 'uses implicit subject' do
    subject.my_method.should be_true
  end

  it 'does not create a subject' do
    MyClass.works?.should be_true
    # subject should not have been created
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subject` appears to be a method which creates the object necessary and returns it.  So it would only create a subject object when called.

It's easy enough to test yourself though...

```
class MyClass
  cattr_accessor :initialized

  def initialize
    MyClass.initialized = true
  end

  def my_method
    true
  end

  def self.works?
    true
  end
end

describe MyClass do
  it 'uses implicit subject' do
    MyClass.initialized = false
    subject.my_method.should be_true
    MyClass.initialized.should == true
  end

  it 'does not create a subject' do
    MyClass.initialized = false
    MyClass.works?.should be_true
    MyClass.initialized.should == false
  end
end
```

Those specs pass, proving that it's lazy.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Would you happen to know where to look in the rspec code to see where subject is implemented?

Comment: No clue.  I guessed, then backed up that guess with a spec to prove the hypothesis.