# Rails 3 + Rspec testing one to many model how to inspect why don't get expected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The following is my model codes,

```
class StudentGrade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grade

  attr_accessible :student_name, :student_grade
  serialize :student_name, :student_grade
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_grades

  def all_grades
   student_grades.map do |sg|
     student_name = sg.student_name
     student_grade = sg.student_grade
     ag = student_name.zip(student_grade)  
   end
  end
end
```

and those are my test codes(rspec),

```
describe Grade do
 let(:grade){ build_stubbed(:grade) }
 let(:student_grades){ [build_stubbed(:student_grades, grade: grade)]}

 describe '#all_grades' do 
   before do 
    student_grades[0].stub(:student_grade).and_return(3)
    student_grades[0].stub(:student_name).and_return("steven")
   end

   subject { grade.all_grades }

   it 'should return an array of student_grade wrapped with student names' do
    should == [["steven",3]]
   end
 end
end
```

So what i don't understand, i can't pass this test as it always gets [] instead of [["steven", 3]].
I don't know what i did is wrong, any one can help?
thanks!

UPDATE:

so i user pry gem to debug. What i found is the two object i stubbed in the test codes, i.e. grade and student_grades, if i use student_grades[0].grade i can call the related grade record but if i call grade.student_grades it returns [] so that is why i kept getting [] as results. I'm not sure why. I'm quite new in Rspec. but good to know!

Comment: Pass a variable (`grade: grade`) instead of Symbol (`grade: :grade`)

Comment: @blelump sorry that was a typo... even passed the variable, it doesn't work

Comment: `let(:student_grades){ [build_stubbed(:student_grades, grade: grade, student_name: 'steven')]}` also please post your factory files

Comment: what returns `student_grades[0].grade`?

Comment: @RajarshiDas that didn't work well either. will post my factory files.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ how can i know what returns student_grades[0].grade? the example returns [], so i think it returns nil.

Comment: @user2775888 just use pry gem for debug: insert to before block: (require 'pry'; binding.pry)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ wow this is great. good for debugging. and also, student_grades[0].grade returns 3. any ideas?

Comment: @user2775888 but why do you use grade.all_grades if grade is an integer?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ actually, see from pry, student_grade_factory (the record in the factory) is returned instead of the values i assign in the before block. any ideas?

Comment: @user2775888 could you update the post with data?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Thank you so much! with pry gem, i debugged myself! i will update my solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess I'd venture that since `let` assigns variables **lazily** you need to first actually reference your **subject** (i.e. `grade`) in order for it be actually be created. The `student_grades` variable is probably being created since it's referenced in a `before` block.

```
it 'should return an array of student_grade wrapped with student name' do
  expect(it).to eq([["steven",3]])
  # ...
end
```

**edit**: Subject is apparently also *lazy*, see this SO answer: [RSpec lazy subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688610/rspec-lazy-subject)

The reason why this will (probably) work, is that you're new effectively **referencing** the subject, which ensures that the lazy evaluation kicks in and instantiates the objects.

Comment: i don't quite understand. i need to write grade.somthing in order to create a grade?

Comment: Ah, no - I'm sorry if the example was misleading. You simply need to *reference* your `grade` object in order for rspec to initialize it. This is a property of lazy evaluation (which `let` and `subject` utilze) - variables are not created until they are referenced.